# Return initial state after state changes

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have to develop web page with list of flights from my data. My data looks like:

```
[
    {
      "id": 123,
      "direction": {
        "from": "Moscow",
        "to": "Berlin"
      },
      "arrival": "2016-06-08T19:52:27.979Z",
      "departure": "2016-06-08T17:51:20.979Z",
      "carrier": "S7"
    },
    {
      "id": 133,
      "direction": {
        "from": "Moscow",
        "to": "Samara"
      },
      "arrival": "2016-09-08T13:52:27.979Z",
      "departure": "2016-08-08T17:51:20.979Z",
      "carrier": "KLM"
    },
    {
      "id": 193,
      "direction": {
        "from": "Moscow",
        "to": "New York"
      },
      "arrival": "2016-06-08T21:52:27.979Z",
      "departure": "2016-06-08T17:51:20.979Z",
      "carrier": "Aeroflot"
    }
  ]
```

I also have a simple filter by carriers. It's just `select` tag in HTML with options: *All, Aeroflot, KLM, S7* and with listener on `onChange` event:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    onChangeHandler(event) {
      if (event.target.value === 'All') {
        dispatch(selectAllCarriers())
      } else {
        dispatch(selectCarrier(event.target.value))
      }
    }
  }
};
```

When I select *KLM* I return this state:

```
[
    {
      "id": 133,
      "direction": {
        "from": "Moscow",
        "to": "Samara"
      },
      "arrival": "2016-09-08T13:52:27.979Z",
      "departure": "2016-08-08T17:51:20.979Z",
      "carrier": "KLM"
    }
  ];
```

When I select *All*, I have to return full list of flights. And I implemented it in reducer:

```
const flights = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'SELECT_CARRIER':
      if (action.carrier === 'All') {
        return state
      } else {
        return state.filter(f => f.carrier === action.carrier);
      }
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

But if I select *KLM* and after *All* I've got just *KLM* flights because my state now includes only *KLM* flights. I don't understand what is the best way to fix my problem and return initial state.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to use selectors instead of removing data from state. When you select carrier you need to set in store that this is the selector you are using and then filter using selector but not removing others flights from the store.

Check this link from Dan Abramov about the use of selectors in Redux.
https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-colocating-selectors-with-reducers?course=building-react-applications-with-idiomatic-redux

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

Rather than filtering in your reducer, you should be filtering the raw data in your component's `select` function. Consider this small change:

```js
const initialState = {
  flights: [],
  filter: undefined
};
const flights = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'SELECT_CARRIER':
      return {
        ...state,
        filter: action.carrier
      };
    case 'SELECT_ALL':
      return {
        ...state,
        filter: undefined
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

And now to access the filtered flights:

```js
const flightsSelector = (state) => {
  if (state.filter) {
    return state.flights.filter(f => f.carrier === state.filter);
  }
  return state.flights;
};
```